# Typescript: resolve relative import path when using symlinks

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, symlink, monorepo

This seems like a dumb question, but I struggle to find the answer.

### The situation

Here is my folder structure:

```bash
myProject/
├── module1/
│   ├── config.ts
│   └── init.ts #symlink
├── module2/
│   ├── config.ts
│   └── init.ts #symlink
└── symlinks/
    └── init.ts # the real not duplicated file
```

The file `init.js` import local files like so:

```js
import config from './config'

// ...
```

### The problem

The problem is that typescript throws **`Cannot find module './config' or its corresponding type declarations`**

I tried playing with typescript option `preserveSymlinks` but it didn't solve my problem

I know about other ways to achieve my goal but it's overkill for just one file and it doesn't solve relaying on a relative path (like creating a npm module, creating a function and pass relative file content as parameter or even generating files at runtime...)

=> I am working with **typescript** in a **monorepo**.

**Is it possible to use symlinks this way? If no, are there other (simple) alternatives?**

**EDIT:** I have made [this example repo](https://github.com/top-kat/typescript-symlinks-test), you can use it as a base for experiments

Comment: What is inside `init.ts` that "forces" you to use something like this?

Comment: It's just relative paths to config files and other local files, the real setup is much more complex and with a lot of files imported. For example, there is a start server script, that is triggered via package.json start command. So it's much harder to create a function and pass configs as parameters for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, TypeScript resolves modules based on the physical path of the file, not the resolved path after following any symbolic links. So, in your case, when you try to import `config` from `./config`, TypeScript looks for the file at the physical path `myProject/module1/config.ts` or `myProject/module2/config.ts`, but it's actually located at `myProject/symlinks/config.ts`.

You can tell TypeScript to resolve modules based on the resolved path by setting the `resolveSymlinks` option to `true` in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "resolveSymlinks": true
  },
  // ...
}
```

This will cause TypeScript to follow symbolic links when resolving modules, so it should be able to find your `config` file. Note that you may also need to set `preserveSymlinks` to `true` if you're using tools like Webpack that may alter the resolved path.

Another option is to use module aliases in your tsconfig.json file to map the `./config` path to the correct location. For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "symlinks/*"]
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

This will tell TypeScript to look for all modules in the `symlinks` directory, as well as in their original locations. Then, you can import `config` like this:

```
import config from 'module1/config';
```

This should work regardless of whether init.ts is a symlink or a regular file.

Comment: Hi, I have already used `preserveSymlinks` options but it was of no use. The problem here are the paths imported **inside** the simlinked files that are relative to the original file and not the symlink file. Have you tried to run a similar project ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can now find a github link with a reproductible example

Comment: `resolveSymlinks` does not exist in the `compilerOptions`.

Comment: This answer is very similar to AI generated. If only because resolveSymlinks is not present (and has never been present) in tsconfig